# How should I calculate if a person is within 50 meters range of a store using geolocation?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, mobile-browser

I have the store's latitude and longitude saved in database, and the user's geolocation is obtained with javascript from his mobile browser.

How should I calculate if the user's distance from the store is within 50m?

Maybe `(x1-x2)**2+(y1-y2)**2 < a certain threshold` ?

p.s. This is like foursquare checkin.

Comment: This won't be needed for < 50m calculations, but it's good to be aware  of this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

Comment: @NeoWang Even if you get a formula for detecting a person within 50meters... is it possible for the geolocator to detect such small difference of distance?

Comment: The wikipeida page also has a link to a JavaScript implementation.

Comment: @sabof your comment is hilarious for those who understand Portuguese :) http://translate.google.pt/#pt/en/wiki%20peida

Comment: The bad words are first words you learn in any language :)

Comment: @NevinMadhukarK Well... is it? Google Maps app use the same geolocator api as the mobile browser, right? And, from product design perspective, I should not allow a user to 'checkin' when he is miles away from the store, or should I?

Comment: @NeoWang No no,you got me wrong.
Am asking whether its possible to detect small distances such as 50m with latitude and longitude method. (Or whatever geolocator method) you use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site ([Calculate distance, bearing and more between Latitude/Longitude points](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)) provide a good explanation and calculation formula. You may want to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

`sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2) < 50`

http://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/distance_formula/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using `javascript`:

```
function calcDistance(p1, p2){
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p2.x-p1.x, 2) + Math.pow(p2.y-p1.y, 2));
}

var store = { x:21, y:36 };
var device = { x:11, y:56 };

console.log( calcDistance(store, device) );
console.log( "Within 50m ? " + (calcDistance(store, device) < 50) );
```

Result:

> `22.360679774997898`
>   `Within 50m ? true`